# Retrieving multiple and repeated keyDown

Tags: javascript, keyboard, windows-8, onkeydown, createjs

I am trying to do a simple pong game for 2 players.

The first one controls his pad with the A and Q (azerty keyboard). The second one controls his pad with the P and M.

Here is the code

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case KEYCODE_ESC:
            break;
        case KEYCODE_UP:
            p1Bitmap.y = p1Bitmap.y - 10;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_DOWN:
            p1Bitmap.y = p1Bitmap.y + 10;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_A:
            p1Bitmap.y = p1Bitmap.y - 10;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_Q:
            p1Bitmap.y = p1Bitmap.y + 10;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_P:
            p2Bitmap.y = p2Bitmap.y - 10;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_M:
            p2Bitmap.y = p2Bitmap.y + 10;
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when player 1 presses on A and player 2 on M, the first player's key gets ignored.

It is possible to get multiple key event repeated ? (for the example of player 1 A and player 2 M I would like to get this : AMAMAMAMAMAMAMAMAMAMAMAMetc instead of just AMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM)

By the way, I am doing this for Windows 8 app (html/css/js) and CreateJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep the movement going until you detect the corresponding `keyup` event.  Start moving on `keydown`, don't stop until `keyup`.

Also, it should be noted that `keydown` is different than `keypress`.  `keydown` will only fire once, no matter how long you hold the key down.  `keypress` on the other hand fires for every time a character is inserted (or would be inserted), so would see repeated events as long as you're holding the key down.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! (strangely, I can't make keypress work ^^ but nevermind)